# App breaks after resigning apk?

Tags: apk, android-emulator

For fun and giggles, i got the latest musical.ly apk, i then used this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with ) to delete the META-INF folder.

Then i ran zip aaligner on it and signed it with apksigner and used the debug.keystore.

used adb install to install it on my emulator.

the app runs, but trying to login gives a "Network" error, even if i did not change ANYTHING in the code.

Is there something i'm missing? i'm totally new to this

Comment: We can only guess, but this sounds like the key to sign the app is used to authenticate the app with the server. A trivial way to deter modified versions of an app.